# Reactjs is not showing anything in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

This is my first time to learn react and I began to watch a tutorial but when I write the code it doesn't show me anything on the browser so what is the problem?
inbox.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ul><li>Thing 1</li><li>Thing 2</li></ul>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and also there is an empty index.css file and all of them are saved in one folder so what is the problem

Comment: How are you serving the HTML/JS? E.g., this works fine if I `python3 -m http.server 9000` it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code here and I no saw nothing wrong. It's correct, is working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwT9E.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIB1u.png)

Comment: Is it possible that the problem comes from VScode or setup?

Comment: I think no, all files are in the same folder?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).